# 2-way binding is lot when using $templateRequest

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-templates

I have a template, which is loaded using $templateRequest. I have a textarea in the template. The textarea populates the value, that is set in the controller. But when I am trying to access the textarea in the controller method, it does not update the value.

**Template**

```
<div class="panel add-notes">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <textarea ng-model="quickNote" rows="5"/>
        <button ng-click="saveNotes()">Add Note</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Method to load the template**

```
$scope.displayPanel = function(templateName){
    var templateURL = resourceURL+templateName+".html";

    $templateRequest(templateURL).then(function(template) {
        $compile($("#modalContent").html(template).contents())($scope);
    },function() {
       //ERROR HANDLER
    });
};
```

**Controller Method**

```
$scope.saveNotes = function(){
    console.log($scope.quickNote);
}
```

In the console log, the value of `quickNote` is displayed as `undefined`. Any resolution?

Comment: Always have a dot in `ng-model` so you are binding to object not a primitive. 2 way binding of primitive gets broken in child scopes.   If you are doing a lot of this pattern of using `$templateRequest` there are much simpler and more standard angular approaches. Are you sure that the modal is in the same scope as your controller?

Comment: Yes, all data are populated. just that the 2-way binding is lost...if i initialize the data in the controller its reflecting...but it does not reflect in controller, if i change it in the text area...

Comment: Use an object in `ng-model` ...this is a golden rule

Comment: yes...that was the solution :) thanks @charlietfl